# selecting when an aggregate column has two or more items

Tags: sql, group-by

Let's say I had a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT 'a' AS a, '1' AS b
UNION 
  SELECT 'a' AS a, '2' AS b
UNION
  SELECT 'b' AS a, '1' AS b) AS a 
GROUP BY a.a
```

In this case "a".b is an aggregate of 1,2 while "b".b is only an aggregate of 1.

How can I select only "a"?

**Question updated to be a bit clearer:**

Let's take this very similar query:

```
SELECT *, GROUP_CONCAT(b) FROM (
  SELECT 'a' AS a, '1' AS b
UNION 
  SELECT 'a' AS a, '2' AS b
UNION
  SELECT 'a' AS a, '3' AS b
UNION
  SELECT 'b' AS a, '1' AS b
UNION
  SELECT 'b' AS a, '2' AS b
) AS a 
GROUP BY a.a
```

Now a.b is 1,2,3 and b.b is 1,2:

I want to select a on the basis that it has 1, 2 and 3.

Comment: @blockhead: which RDBMS do you use?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  a
FROM    (
        SELECT 'a' AS a, '1' AS b
        UNION 
        SELECT 'a' AS a, '2' AS b
        UNION
        SELECT 'b' AS a, '1' AS b
        ) AS a
GROUP BY
        a
HAVING  COUNT(*) > 1
```

Note that `*` syntax that you are using is a `MySQL`'s extension which should not be used like this.

`a.b` in this case would be not an aggregate: it would be a random record from the group `'a'`.

Comment: This wouldn't in a situation where a.b was 1,2,3 and b.b was 1,2.

Comment: @blockhead: this wouldn't what?

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear in my question. I want to select "a" on the basis that it has 1 and 2.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT a.a,COUNT(*) AS CountOf FROM (
  SELECT 'a' AS a, '1' AS b
UNION 
  SELECT 'a' AS a, '2' AS b
UNION
  SELECT 'b' AS a, '1' AS b) AS a 
GROUP BY a.a
HAVING  COUNT(*) > 1
```

OUTPUT:

```
a    CountOf
---- -----------
a    2

(1 row(s) affected)
```

**EDIT** based on OP's Comment:

> This wouldn't in a situation where a.b
>   was 1,2,3 and b.b was 1,2

try this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 a.a,COUNT(*) AS CountOf FROM (
  SELECT 'a' AS a, '1' AS b
UNION 
  SELECT 'a' AS a, '2' AS b
UNION 
  SELECT 'a' AS a, '3' AS b
UNION 
  SELECT 'b' AS a, '1' AS b
UNION
  SELECT 'b' AS a, '2' AS b) AS a 
GROUP BY a.a
ORDER BY 2 DESC
```

OUTPUT:

```
a    CountOf
---- -----------
a    3

(1 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: First of all, your POC is not mimicking my scenario...you set up a.b = 1,2,3 and b.b = 1. Second of all, I still think you've missed the point of my question.

Comment: @blockhead, I changed my sample run so a.b=1,2,3 and b.b=1,2 (which changes nothing in the output).  Other than what i have in my answer, I have no idea what you are asking.  You need to do a better job explaining what you are after, short of that I give up. you say `How can I select only "a"?` you need to say how we determine (most rows in column b, lowest value in column a, etc.) what rows to return for you.

Comment: To make the answer sample a little less contrived...imagine that 1,2 and 3 are tags, and I want to select all the entities that have tags 1,2,3

Answer (score 0):

The following seems to work for me:

```
SELECT a,b FROM (
    SELECT a,b FROM (
      SELECT 'a' AS a, '1' AS b
    UNION 
      SELECT 'a' AS a, '2' AS b
    UNION
      SELECT 'a' AS a, '3' AS b
    UNION
      SELECT 'b' AS a, '1' AS b
    UNION
      SELECT 'b' AS a, '2' AS b
    ) AS a 
) b WHERE b.b IN ({x1},{x2}...)
GROUP BY b.a HAVING COUNT(b.b) = 2
```

Where x1, etc. are the values of "b" that I want to restrict.

For example, in this case

```
WHERE b.b IN (1,2,3)
```

will return "a"

```
WHERE b.b IN (1,2)
```

will return "a" and "b"

and

```
WHERE b.b IN (2,3)
```

will return only "a"

I'm not sure why this works, but it seems to.